# Error when trying to insert with PHP / PDO / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to make an insertion with two parameters and I'm getting this return:

*PDOStatement::bindValue() expects parameter 3 to be int, string given in.*

**No meu banco tenho id(AUTO_INCREMENT), nome(VARCHAR) e Localizaçao (VARCHAR).
My function to insert is this one**

```
public function inserir() { //create
        $query = 'insert into tb_usuarios(name,localizacao)values(:name,:location:)';
        $stmt = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue('$name','$location', $this->location->__get('name','location'));
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

I already tried to put the Id in the insertion query and I didn't get any results, this code is from another project that I did the insertion of only one field, but all the other 3 fields in the table were Aut-increment

Comment: The post needs to be entirely in English. Or post it under https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: aqui tens que escrever en ingles o vai para https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: That isn't how to use a PDO prepared statement. Consult the manuals for this https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php - https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: I posted on pt.stack but redirected to this one, sorry.

Comment: @Funk fort Niner I reviewed the question, can you please reopen it?

Comment: I noticed the edit, I did vote to reopen. I don't have the power to reopen in one shot, others have to vote to reopen. I think it's 3 votes needed.

Comment: @PatricEnderson You say you were redirected back to this area of Stack. You might want to flag your question for moderation and tell them about that. It could be a bug.

Comment: I had stack.ptbr open and I don't know why I'm registered. I posted there, but I remained how to post here, try to delete a post here, but I will not let myself post because it was here, so it was brief for a new post

Answer (score 0):

The PDO function `bindValue()` accepts one parameter at a time. You can't bind all of them in one call.

The code you were trying to write should look like this:

```
public function inserir() { //create
        $query = 'insert into tb_usuarios(name,localizacao)values(:name,:location:)';
        $stmt = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue('name',$this->location->__get('name'));
        $stmt->bindValue('location',$this->location->__get('location'));
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

You can also make an array of param name=>value pairs, and pass that array to `execute()` which does the same thing as using `bindValue()` for each param.

```
public function inserir() { //create
        $query = 'insert into tb_usuarios(name,localizacao)values(:name,:location:)';
        $stmt = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
        $params = [
          'name'=>$this->location->__get('name'),
          'location'=>$this->location->__get('location')
        ];
        $stmt->execute($params);
    }
```

Note another difference: For a placeholder like `:name` you can use a param key `':name'` or `'name'`, but `'$name'` will not work.